# Delay after final print statement before ending the program. Core dumped in c equivalent

Tags: python, c

There is a good amount of delay (~7-8s) after the final print statement before the program ends while running this code.

```
li = []

for i in range(100000000): # A very huge number
    li.append(i)

print("Done.")
```

Pypy worked much faster and showed the expected behaviour.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Stack overflow? Usual 1MB vs your expected 400MB.

Comment: Please ask only one question. Also, what is "reasonable time"? What do you want to ask about? Python or C or what?

Comment: it took 20 seconds in python for the program to finish execution. And it was delay of around 7-8 seconds after the final print statement.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your results!

This was run on Google Colab CPU instance

It is taking `00.000093` seconds for print statement and program to end!

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from tqdm import tqdm
start = dt.now()
li = []

for i in tqdm(range(100000000)): # A very huge number
    li.append(i)
print('\n')
print('Time to run:',dt.now()-start)
start = dt.now()
print("Done.")
print('Time after run:',dt.now()-start)
```

```
100%|██████████| 100000000/100000000 [00:33<00:00, 3010464.83it/s]

Time to run: 0:00:34.386686
Done.
Time after run: 0:00:00.000093
```

Comment: I am on a terminal and the results for me are almost same as yours. The delay is after the print is executed i.e. before I can do anything on the terminal again. And my computer almost freezes in that time.